Qute with quarkus is driving me nuts
I am using and loving Quarkus, but the Qute template engine is driving me nuts.
All the time I have to execute mvn clean and restart Quarkus in dev mode, otherwise I get
[error]: Build step io.quarkus.qute.deployment.QuteProcessor#collectCheckedTemplates threw an exception: io.quarkus.qute.TemplateException: Parameter names not recorded for com.projects.terminplaner.app.resources.ConfirmationResource$Templates: compile the class with -parameters

I tried a bunch of different Quarkus versions, I am now on version 3.15.1 (latest as of today).
My environment
Apache Maven 3.9.2 (c9616018c7a021c1c39be70fb2843d6f5f9b8a1c)
Maven home: /Users/schube/.sdkman/candidates/maven/current
Java version: 21.0.4, vendor: Eclipse Adoptium, runtime: /Users/schube/.sdkman/candidates/java/21.0.4-tem
Default locale: de_AT, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "13.5.2", arch: "aarch64", family: "mac"

My pom.xml does have the parameters setting like the Quarkus templates suggest:
        <compiler-plugin.version>3.13.0</compiler-plugin.version>
        ........
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${compiler-plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <parameters>true</parameters>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

Since a mvn clean helps most of the time (not always) without any changes on the templates, I am pretty sure this is a bug in Quarkus and/or Qute or my specific environment. But I do not know where to start, to solve this annoying thing.

Poor title. Rewrite to summarize your specific technical issue.

That looks like a bug.
The best thing you can do is to file a new issue here: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues.
Ideally, provide a simple reproducer app + steps to reproduce. This will speed up the whole process.
